# SyntaxNode serialization and deserialization error with MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn

For the past few days i tried to resolve this problem again after a few months of ignoring it.

I took out the part which causes problems reduced the program to just serialization and deserialization.
It seems that MemoryStream or CSharpSyntaxNode when used first time in the program does not want that it's first operation to be deserialization. But this begs the question: why would be one of this objects sensitive to what operation you run first?

Steps to recreate:

1.Open the program, seed so you have a value then get the node and set the byte array as many times you want. [Init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKpbw.jpg)

2a. Restart the program and set the byte array to the value before restart then get the node. It will crash  [Restart-A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRTtf.jpg)

2b. Restart the program, **run test**, set the byte array to the value before restart then get the node. It will work. [Restart-B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbkPz.jpg)

Here is the link for the [project](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/63b8251773366a2ae158a1e51ed21e4520180528215746/29e8a8). It uses net core 2.1.

Comment: Looks like one of the objects may be null.   Is CSharpSyntaxNode a static object or an instance of a class?  usually an object starting with a capital letter is static, but the person who wrote the code may not a used standard naming conventions.

Comment: Can you create [a small self-contained example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @svick I added a small project.

Comment: @jdweng This is the naming convention used in Roslyn, that is not mine and it is an abstract class and child of SyntaxNode that is specific to C#

Comment: @RobertRaicu Can you remove everything that's not relevant to this question from your code? It's probably not related to database, so remove everything related to that. It's almost certainly not related to ASP.NET Core, so make it a console application. It makes it much easier for us to figure out what's going on.

Comment: It seems [you figured out what the issue is](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/27226). Do you want to answer this question with what you learned and then accept that answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a deeper problem here based inside the Roslyn compiler. The current version does not seem to be able to do it. At the moment of the writing it's not know if it's designed to work like this or it's a bug. You can look for specifics on the opened ticket here: [Roslyn Github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/27226)